# Chrome Devtools mobile repsonsive View shows wrong size

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Couldn't find anything about this so I ask this here:

I got a really simple page and wanted an element to be full width (`width: 100vw`). I noticed that at a smaller screen than around 300px it got smaller and wasn't actual full width.

No inserted a complete new div on top of all my html, gave it a `background: black;` with `height: 100vh;` and `width: 100vw;` and it's actually not the full screen size.

As you can see in my screenshot, the set "display size" is 352px x 778 and the element *should* be 352x778 (so exact the screensize), but as you can see it's smaller.

What causes this and how do I fix it? What is correct now? What I see or what the value says? It's pretty annoying.

If needed: I use chrome 89.0.4389.114 on macOS Big Sur Version 11.2.3 (20D91)

Added while inserting code: 
As I reduced the code to post it here, I see that the wrapper is the problem. But this question is still valid I believe. Why is the wrapper thats not connected with the `<header>` a problem for the viewport?
[image]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">

  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="user">
      <h2>
        Lorem Ipsum,
        <br> Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet!
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Has been stucked for 2 days, and I found that it is actually the zoom rate of chrome is affecting the element size under devTool's responsive model.

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEdFF.png" style="width: 80vw;">
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEdFF.png)

The zoom rate of your current brower is affecting the element size:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpAdd.png" style="width: 80vw;">
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpAdd.png)

Answer (score -1):

read more about scales in webpage with desktop browser or mobile browser

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag